# ASP.NET MVC 5 Force all users to logout (using cookie auth)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with cookie-based authentication. I want to make a change in user roles and enforce it right away, but roles don't change until a user logs out and back in.

How can I force all users to logout or to renew their identity cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is pretty easy. You can change the cookie name (default is ASP.NET_SessionId, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookiename?view=netframework-4.8)).

This causes the website to look for a different session cookie name, making the old cookies invalid.

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
        CookieName = "[NewNameHere]",
    });
}
```